# How to ignore some files in Delphi QA audits?

Tags: delphi, static-analysis

I'm using the fabulous **Audits** tool within Delphi XE.
It's really useful because it founds some architecture smells, coding rules violations ...

BUT, I had not found any way to ignore some files. I have 3rd Party files (auto-generated from XML Data Binding) that produce many warnings ... The report is then polluted as I would like to ignore these files and see only 0 warning when I'm done.

**Any way to ignore files in Audits tool?**

Comment: I would use a script tool like Apache Ant, use it to copy the relevant files to a new clean directory and then invoke the QA Audits. Unfortunately (iirc) the QA Audits can not be run from command line.

Comment: @mjn Audits can be run from command line : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/AuditsCLI.EXE,_the_Command_Line_Audits_and_Metrics_Tool

Comment: That would be a great QualityCentral request `{$PRAGMA NO_AUDIT}` or something like that, as a precompiler directive at the top of the file.

Comment: @mjn   In that case you can script it to do what you want